# The canvas hitbox does not match between scene and game windows

Tags: unity-game-engine

Some of the canvas match but some does not.

Edit:
Also I can't see those white triangle (do they call anchor?) in my broken canvas. While white triangle do exist in the working canvas. I think this is the reason. How to get those white triangle back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on your setup? I can see you are using a world space canvas for example

Comment: @pixlhero Please look at my update edit.

Comment: what is that white rectangle? cant see it in the pictures.